# React JS Error: is not defined no-undef

Tags: react-redux

I am a beginner developer at redux

my actions/cart.js

```
export default addToCart = (item) => {
    console.log("item: " + item);
    return {
        type: 'ADD'.
        item
    };

}
```

and reducers/cart.js

```
export default (state = [], payload) => {
    switch (payload.type) {
        case 'ADD':
            return [...state, payload.item];
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

linter says:

```
./src/actions/cart.js

  Line 1:  'addToCart' is not defined  no-undef
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
export default function addToCart (item) {
    console.log("item: " + item);
    return {
        type: 'ADD'.
        item
    };
}
```

Or

```
export const addToCart = (item) => {
    console.log("item: " + item);
    return {
        type: 'ADD'.
        item
    };

}
```

Especially `function` way is better as it enables `default` export. Your solution does not work, cause you wrote `addToCart`, not `const addToCart`, so it thinks that `addToCart` is defined.